# Fortran 77. Pass array by reference

Tags: arrays, fortran77

I need to pass array to subrobroutine by reference. Instead of this interpreter make copy of matrix. And static matrix in MAIN remains like `{{0,0}{0,0}{0,0}}`. I know in fortran all vars by defauly pass by reference. What I do wrong ?

```
 PROGRAM LAB1
    IMPLICIT NONE
    Real pointsOfTriangle(2,3)
    call newTriangle(pointsOfTriangle)
    call getTriangle(pointsOfTriangle)

    pause
  END

  SUBROUTINE newTriangle(pointsOfTrinagle)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    Real pointsOfTriangle(2,3)
    Integer i

    do i=1,3
        print *,'enter x,y:'
        read *,pointsOfTriangle(1,i),pointsOfTriangle(2,i)
    end do

    do i=1,3
        print *,'x[', i,']=',pointsOfTriangle(1,i)
        print *,'y[', i,']=',pointsOfTriangle(2,i)
        print *,' '
    end do

  END

  SUBROUTINE getTriangle(pointsOfTriangle)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    Real pointsOfTriangle(2,3)
    Integer i

    do i=1,3
        print *,'x[', i,']=',pointsOfTriangle(1,i)
        print *,'y[', i,']=',pointsOfTriangle(2,i)
        print *,' '
    end do

  END
```

Comment: Good grief, someone is still teaching Fortran at this day and age? The 77 version even.

Comment: Whatever OP writes that code isn't FORTRAN 77, `implicit none` was introduced with Fortran 90.

Comment: @George: a trinagle is a polynog with three vertices.

Comment: I use open watcom compiler. There support Fortran'77 and some features from 90.

Comment: if you set your compiler flags to warn you about accessing uninitialized variables it should catch your spelling mistake.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My lecturer recommended the use of common blocks. Syntax COMMON/tag/varibleName. That's like global vars in C/C++, but this more safely, because you specify which functions and subroutines can see there.

And one feature for common blocks.

```
COMMON/vertex/x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3
```

That works because in array varibles are consistently.

```
  PROGRAM LAB1
    IMPLICIT NONE
    Real pointsOfTriangle(2,3)
    COMMON/vertex/pointsOfTriangle
    call newTriangle(pointsOfTriangle)
    call getTriangle(pointsOfTriangle)

    pause
  END

  SUBROUTINE getTriangle
    IMPLICIT NONE
    Real pointsOfTriangle(2,3)
    COMMON/vertex/pointsOfTriangle
    Integer i

    do i=1,3
        print *,'x[', i,']=',pointsOfTriangle(1,i)
        print *,'y[', i,']=',pointsOfTriangle(2,i)
        print *,' '
    end do

  END
```

Comment: Recommending COMMON blocks in 2013 is like recommending motorists to keep a spare glass jar of petroleum distillate in their automobile.  Just don't do it.  And if your lecturer recommends that you do, TWEP him or her.

Answer (score 1):

I've now compiled your code, fixing the spelling mistake in line 10 along the way, and run it.  It seems to work fine.

What evidence do you have that your 'interpreter' copies the matrix ?  (I've put quotation marks around the word interpreter because I don't think you use the term correctly.)

You write that you know *in fortran all vars by defauly pass by reference*.  You are subtly mistaken.  The Fortran standards do not require that processors (the standard term for what you call 'interpreter', and a bit more besides) pass arguments by reference, just that they behave as if they do.  Behind the scenes the processor is free to do what the heck it likes, I think in the old days with some compilers arguments were passed by little elves.  Leaving that aside most Fortran processors that I have ever used (and all the ones I currently use) do, by default, pass arguments by reference so I think that it is unusual for you to have one which does not.  That's why I'd like to know why you think yours has this unusual feature.  You might even tell us what compiler you are using.

Finally, some unsought advice: move your program `end` statement to the end of your entire source and after the `pause` statement in line 9 insert a line containing only the word `contains`.  This rearrangement will make your subroutines internal to your program and your compiler will generate code to ensure that they are called correctly -- with the right number of arguments of the right types, that sort of thing.  You'll also have to put the word `subroutine` on the `end` statements which end the subroutine definitions.